# In an xs:any type XML element, does the namespace wildcard ##any also include #local?

Tags: xml, xsd, wildcard, xml-namespaces

In an xs:any type XML element, does the namespace wildcard ##other also include #local ?

As far as I can see from the following it does not, e.g.:

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043(v=vs.110).aspx

The definitions from the 2nd link above seems to be disjunct as far as I can see:

`Elements from any namespace that is not the target namespace of the parent element containing this element can be present.`

`Elements that are not qualified with a namespace can be present.`

Is this correct, and did I understand it correctly? There must be no unqualified elements in an XML element of type `xs:any` with `##other` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`##local` permits names that are in no namespace

`##other` permits names that are in a namespace other than the target namespace

You need to be very careful with the terminology here. Using colloquial terms like "unqualified elements" isn't going to help you, because the spec uses terms very precisely and assumes you know what they mean. In particular, many of us think of "names in no namespace" as being in some kind of special "unnamed" or "null" namespace, but to think that is a bad mistake when it comes to reading the XSD spec. When the spec says the name must be in a namespace other than the target namespace, it means (a) it must be in a namespace (thus excluding no-namespace names - the ones that match `##local`), and (b) that namespace must not be the target namespace.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. i didn't think of "no namespace" as some kind of special "null namespace". Quite the opposite, but I couldn't be sure that wasn't the intention. I just needed a less ambiguous natural language explanation of the slightly odd descriptions. This is perfect.